# The geometric and arithmetic mean of two positive numbers

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I don't have really any idea about it 
Use the inequality :
$
\mathit{\alpha}\mathit{\beta}\mathrm{\leq}\mathop{\int}\limits_{0}\limits^{\mathit{\alpha}}{{t}^{{p}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}}{dt}\mathrm{{+}}\mathop{\int}\limits_{0}\limits^{\mathit{\beta}}{{u}^{{q}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}}{du}\mathrm{{=}}\frac{{\mathit{\alpha}}^{p}}{p}\mathrm{{+}}\frac{{\mathit{\beta}}^{q}}{q}
$

To show that the geometric mean of two positive numbers does not exceed the arithmetic mean .

Comment: *Hint*: $p=q=2$

Comment: Can you be more specific if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

another proof is to work backwards, namely $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$$ after squaring for $$a\geq0,b\geq 0$$ we get
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{4}\geq ab$$ multiplying by $4$ we get
$$a^2+b^2+2ab\geq 4ab$$ and we get
$$(a-b)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: Can you show me how we can prove that by the relation that I wrote up